# Name only the first bars in facet plots

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to reduce clutter when plotting bars for different categories. That is, I use facets to compare the same categorical variables by other categorial variables.

For example, I use the `tips` dataset from `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(tips, aes(x=time)) +
  geom_bar(shape=1) +
  facet_grid(. ~ sex)
```

The result is:
[image]

My desired change is that "Dinner" and "Lunch" only appear below the "Female" facet. I tried

```
scale_x_discrete(labels = c("with", "without", "", ""))
```

but of course without effect since there are only two categories within the variable `time`, so why take more than two elements in the labels vector? How can I accomplish my desired graph without the "draw two graphs and combine them"-workaround?

Comment: For something like this, you could consider mapping `fill = time` and turning the x-axis labels completely off.

Comment: No that won't work because there is already a variable. I only reduced the data in the example.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify components of a ggplot using `ggplot_build` and `ggplot_gtable`:

```
x <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
```

If you look at `str(x)`, you can then figure out where to change labels:

```
x$grobs[[8]]$children$axis$grobs[[2]]$label <- c('', '')
plot(x)
```

However, it's important to note that this may not work with future versions of **ggplot2** if they decide to change the internal structure of plots.

[image]

Comment: I this really the only solution? Because there are two things I don't like about it: 1. It is very slow with my data (a stacked bar plot with six facets and two x-axis-ticks each), and 2. I can't see the entire content of `str(...)`, because the console windows is too small. Also, it says `Error in object[[i]] : subscript out of bounds`.

Comment: Yeah, I get that error, too. This is the only solution, however. In all fairness to ggplot2, though, your's is a very strange request.

Comment: Why? When there's seven times the same sequence of just two words, it reduces clutter a lot when printing only one sequence.